# how to test contenteditable div using angular e2e?

Tags: angularjs, contenteditable

I am trying to set value to content editable div by using angular e2e test .
following is the snippet.

```
it('compare value - Launch form', function() {
            element('#firstLine').val(123)
                element('#enter').click();
            sleep(10);
            expect(element('#secondLine').val()).toBe(123);
});
```

Comment: what problems do you have and what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to set value 123 to the first input box which is contenteditable div.Then pressing enter button which sets the first value to the second inputbox.then comparing the values but value 123 is not displayed in the first input box.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you hadn't solved your problem already:

I believe element(id).val(..) is for input type elements. For contenteditable divs you should set text with:

element(id).text("some text")
expect(element(id).text()).toEqual("some text")

You can also use your angular model to put some text in your field, e.g.
input("model.property").enter("some text")